# How to read this specific pbf file

Tags: python, gis, openstreetmap, arcgis, osm.pbf

I couldn't read this kind of pbf file :

```
https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification/
```

with some of tutorials available in internet ,

any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will not read this cause this is not an osm.pbf file but vector tile. Not every pbf is osm.pbf

Comment: Thanks , can i convert to other formats? like json for example?

Answer (score 0):

Try Osmreads. you can find example and installation process here-

https://github.com/dezhin/osmread

Comment: I tried that , but didnt get the result , can u do it for the url i gave ?